# High-level Compare And Swap (CAS) functions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, multicore, atomic

I'd like to document what high-level (i.e. C++ not inline assembler ) functions or macros are available for Compare And Swap (CAS) atomic primitives...

E.g., WIN32 on x86 has a family of functions `_InterlockedCompareExchange` in the `<_intrin.h>` header.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll let others list the various platform-specific APIs, but for future reference in C++09 you'll get the

```
atomic_compare_exchange()
```

operation in the new "Atomic operations library".

Answer (score 9):

glib, a common system library on Linux and Unix systems (but also supported on Windows and Mac OS X), defines [several atomic operations](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.16/glib-Atomic-Operations.html), including **g_atomic_int_compare_and_exchange** and **g_atomic_pointer_compare_and_exchange**.

Answer (score 6):

GCC has some [built-ins for atomic accesses](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html), too.

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris there is "atomic.h" (i.e. [<sys/atomic.h>](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/atomic.h)).

Answer (score 2):

MacOS X has [OSAtomic.h](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/OSAtomic/CompositePage.html)

Answer (score 2):

There have been a series of working group papers on this subject proposing changes to the C++ Standard Library. [WG N2427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html) (*C++ Atomic Types and Operations*) is the most recent, which contributes to section 29 -- *Atomic operations library* -- of the pending standard.

Answer (score 1):

java has this CAS operation, too

see [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.html#compareAndSet(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object))

there are practical uses for this, like a [lock-free hashtable](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2139967204534450862&ei=h8jhSM61N6Ky2gKK2LydCw&q=hashtable&emb=1) used in multiprocessor system

Comment: The question is tagged C++ ;)